# Slots inside QThread running concurrently

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtimer, worker-thread

I have two classes a Handler and a Worker connected with signal and slots. Here is a simplified version (pseudo code):

Handler Constructor:

```
Handler::Handler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_workerThread = new QThread;
    m_worker = new Worker;
    m_worker->moveToThread(m_workerThread);
    m_workerThread->start();

    connect(this, &Handler::doWork, m_worker, &Worker::doWork);
    connect(this, &Handler::stopWork, m_worker, &Worker::stopWork);

    emit doWork();
}
```

Worker

```
void Worker::doWork()
{
    qDebug()<<"------"
    qDebug()<<"Start do work executing in: "<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    //doing some work
    m_timer->start();//a singleshot timer that calls doWork() on timeout
    qDebug()<<"work done";
    qDebug()<<"------" 

}

void Worker::stopWork()
{
    qDebug()<<"Stop timer executing in: "<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    m_timer->stop(); 
}
```

So basically work is started after emitting "doWork" from the Handler. The "doWork" slot has a singleshot timer that calls the same function again after a a certain time.
Some time later the Handler emits a "stopWork" signal.
Here is my debug output:

```
------
Start do work executing in: 0x65602450
work done
------
------
Start do work executing in: 0x65602450
work done
------
------
Start do work executing in: 0x65602450
work done
------
------
Start do work executing in: 0x65602450
stop work emitted from handler in: 0x750a7000
Stop timer executing in: 0x65602450
work done
------
------
Start do work executing in: 0x65602450
work done
------
etc...
```

So what I don't understand is how is it even possible that my worker thread executes two slots (doWork, and stopWork) at the same time? Shouldn't the stopWork signal get posted and wait for the thread to become Idle before executing "stopWork" slot?

Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce this using a minimal working example, but I'm hoping from the code I posted It's clear what I'm missing.

Also from my tests I figured this is happening 30-40% of the time.

Comment: What happens in the "//doing some work" part of `Worker::doWork`?  If, at any point during that code, control is handed back (however briefly) to the event loop then I think it would be perfectly possible for another queued signal to begin processing.  Hence your slots aren't executing in parallel they're actually nested.

Comment: I'm calling some functions implemented by other classes. Could you please give me some examples of how control is handed back to the event loop? I can than see if it's the case in the functions I'm calling!

Comment: Thank you very much for the Hint. You were right. I found out the code I was calling is using "QCoreApplication::processEvents() "

Answer (score 0):

Using Thread synchronization classes like QMutex and/or QSemaphore might solve your problem.

For example, if you had created a QMutex in your Handler class and passed it to your worker thread:

```
Handler::Handler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    //Class variable : QMutex* mutex
    mutex = new QMutex();
    m_workerThread = new QThread;
    m_worker = new Worker;
    m_worker->moveToThread(m_workerThread);
    m_workerThread->start();

    connect(this, &Handler::doWork, m_worker, &Worker::doWork);
    connect(this, &Handler::stopWork, m_worker, &Worker::stopWork,Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);

    emit doWork(mutex);
}
```

and then called this common QMutex's lock mechanism from inside the other thread:

```
void Worker::doWork(QMutex* mutex)
{
    mutex->lock();
    qDebug()<<"------"
    qDebug()<<"Start do work executing in: "<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    //doing some work
    m_timer->start();//a singleshot timer that calls doWork() on timeout
    qDebug()<<"work done";
    qDebug()<<"------" 
    mutex->unlock();

}
```

And used the same logic in your Handler class, just before you emit the "stop" signal:

```
...
mutex->lock();
emit stopWork();
mutex->unlock();
...
```

This way you could have avoided an unwanted concurrency.

BlockingQueuedConnection flag here assures that your main thread doesn't advance without the stopping job is complete, therefore not unlocking the mutex before the job is done.

This is the logic I'm trying to utilize while tackling concurrency situations and data racing, I hope it helps you too.

Comment: the problem is this will probably produce a deadlock, because I will be trying to lock the Mutex twice from the same Thread

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't realize you activate the same slot through a singleshot timer.  
But this does not change the main fact, your apparent need to synchronize the threads.   
In that case, you can add `mutex->unlock()` line into a timeout triggered slot before calling your actual `Worker::doWork` slot again. That way, a deadlock  would be avoided in your Worker thread.